# Detect users position on web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I have a single HTML page. 2000 pixels long for example. I want to detect if a visitor reaches a certain point on the page.

The page structure:

- 0px = begin of the page;
- 500px = about us page;
- 1000px = contactpage;

Is there a way with jQuery to detect if a user reaches the points described above?

Comment: Check my answer below. You can detect if the element is currently visible when scrolling even without knowing its position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want jQuery's [`scroll`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event-binding function.

Comment: Yes: Use the 'scroll' event to call a function every time the user scrolls, regardless of how the scrolling is done (mouse, finger, keyboard, ..). 'scrollTop' tells you where the scroll bar is currently located.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I would create three divs and then have a mouse over event on each.  Example:

```
$("#begin").mouseover(function(){
   alert("over begin");
});

$("#about").mouseover(function(){
   alert("over about");
});

$("#contact").mouseover(function(){
   alert("over contact");
});
```

You can see a working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ezj9F/

Comment: Thanks for your solution! How to detect this on a mobile device?

Comment: And what if they're using the scrollbar, or the keyboard, or any other type of navigation system? What if they happen to not mouse over the element? onScroll would be a much better event to detect, along with a hit test type function for visibility.

Comment: @Jordan, this would not work for scrollbar or keyboard.  Only mouseover.  It's not entirely clear to me what "visitor reaches" means so this may or may not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try [**THIS**](http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/5VbYE/) working snippet.

Using this code you don't have to know position of the element you want to check if it is visible.

#### JQuery

```
var $window = $(window);
// # of pixels from the top of the document to the top of div.content
var contentTop = $("div.content").offset().top;
// content is visible when it is on the bottom of the window and not at the top
var contentStart = contentTop - $window.height();
// content is still visible if any part of his height is visible
var contentEnd = contentTop + $("div.content").height();

$window.scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
  if(scrollTop > contentStart && scrollTop < contentEnd) {
    console.log('You can see "HELLO"!');
  } else {
    console.log('You cannot see "HELLO"!');
  }
});
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="scroll"></div>
<div class="content">HELLO</div>
<div class="scroll"></div>
```

#### CSS

```
div.scroll {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 100px;
  height: 1000px;
}

div.content {
  background-color: #bada55;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

*EDIT*: Now the algorithm is checking if any part of the `div.content` is visible (it is considering height of the element). If you are not interested in that change `contentEnd` to `var contentEnd = contentTop`.